# Printing tabs(#9) with fmx.Printer does not work in firemonkey

Tags: delphi, printing, firemonkey, delphi-xe7

When i try to print a line of text with tabs(#9) in them, the tabs are trimmed

```
Text = '- Hardware:'#9#9'Virtual server'
Printer.canvas.FillText(MyRect,Text,False,1,[], TTextAlign.taLeading, TTextAlign.taLeading);
```

But the tabs are not printed and the text is not seperated.
Is there a function to mimic tabs?

Comment: Canvas.FillText doesn't know anything about tabs. You will have to add the spaces yourself in the text.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can add your text lines to a TMemo with memo1.lines.add and then use memo1.PaintTo to paint the formatted text to the printer canvas ? Depends if you can make do with a single font and the limited formatting of Tmemo.

Otherwise you have to work out the tab positions and draw the words individually.

Comment: The simple formatting is not enough. I had to fill the spaces myself and guess the tab width.